Sharepoint workflow trigger issue when user has Create but no Edit permissions - even with App Step
On Sharepoint Server 2019, I want a user to be able to submit to a list, but not edit any submitted items - not even their own. I want particular users to only see their own submission. I also want this item to trigger a workflow with an app step.
My problem is that the user is successfully able to create items and not edit them, and they only see their own - however the workflow stalls on "Started" with a "HTTP Unauthorized" and "Access denied" error.
To repeat my problem:
Site Actions > Site Permissions > Create a New Permission level called "Submit Only". Within this level select only "Add items" and "View items".
Create a list on the site called "Test List" , and under list settings > Advanced > Set Item-level permissions to: "Read items that were created by the user" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user.
On "Test List" go to List Settings > Permissions for this List. add a user and grant the user "Submit Only" permissions.
In SharePoint designer create a new Sharepoint 2013 workflow for this list. Within the list create a new 2013 workflow. Add an App step in the workflow which has a simple action - such as logging or email. Set it to trigger when a list item is created.
Anything else I can do here to make this work?
Thank you
